# Laravel casts strings to numbers in DB queries?

Tags: sql, laravel, casting

I have a table of `players` with a field called `name` (which is a string, of course). When adding a player to the database, I check for uniqueness using a custom rule:

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    return !($this->players->where('name', $value)->count());
}
```

This works most of the time. I noticed, however, that strings are cast to numbers whenever possible. For example, if there is a player with the name `"123"`, then I cannot add a new player whose name is `"0000123"` or `"123."` or other such variations with leading or trailing zeroes. Or, for example, if the DB has a player called "9.87e2", then I can't add "987".

As a sanity check, I logged `gettype($value)` inside the function and confirmed that it is always a string. I then tried replicating the issue in a SQL sandbox, but everything worked as expected. Does that mean this is a bug in Laravel?

Comment: This doesn't seem right. What is the datatype of `name` in your database?(`DESCRIBE players;`, or post your `migration`). If the database can handle `00123` and `123` as separate entities, and you don't have `protected $casts = ['name' => 'integer'];` on your `Player` model, then all should be well. Sidenote, `$this->players->where()` doesn't directly query the database, but rather the resulting `Collection` of `$this->players()->get()`. This might be better as `$this->players()->where('name', $value)->count()` (`->players()` vs `->players`, without the `()`).

Comment: @TimLewis Aha! Your last suggestion (i.e., adding the parentheses) fixed it. Thanks for your help. I guess I don't understand the difference between `->players` and `->players()`.

Comment: No worries! Quick explanation,`->players` (without the `()`) will execute `$this->players()->get()` behind the scenes, which results in a `Collection`, which has a `->where()` method, which searches against the records in that `Collection` and not the Database. `->players()`, with the `()`, is a Query, which searches directly against the DB. You'd then execute `->get()`, `->count()`, etc, like `$this->players()->where(...)->get()`

Comment: @TimLewis Okay, that makes more sense now, and also explains why I wasn't able to use `players->get()` when debugging, because the players were already implicitly got. Thanks again. (And if you copy/paste your comment to an answer, I'll accept it.)

Comment: Sure thing! When I get a sec, I'll translate that to an answer. Cheers! And you're correct; `->players->get()` can work, but you need to pass something to `->get()`, like `->players->get('name')`. See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue doesn't seem to be casting, but rather loose comparison on `name` when using `->where()` on the resulting `Collection` vs `->where()` on the Database layer. Compare:

```php
$this->players->where('name', $value)->count();
```

In the above, `$this->players` will be a `Collection` of all `Player` records from the Database associated with `$this` (another Model I assume). This is the equivalent of something like:

```php
$players = collect([
  ['id' => 1, 'name' => '123'],
  ['id' => 2, 'name' => '234'],
  // ...
]);

$players->where('name', '123')->count();    // 1
$players->where('name', '000123')->count(); // 1 (That's odd...)
$players->where('name', '234')->count();    // 1
$players->where('name', '345')->count();    // 0
// ... Ect etc.
```

In the above examples, you can see that the "loose" comparison on `name`, using `'00123'` and `'123'` both returns 1. This is problematic, as the Database can handle `'000123'` and `'123'` as distinct entities, but querying against a `Collection` cannot.

To get around this, we should query directly against the Database, using the `players` **method** instead of **property** (`()` denotes a method, lack of `()` denotes a property):

```php
$query = $this->players()->where('name', $value); // Omitted the `count()` for now
```

At this point in time, `$query` is a Database Query (`Builder` instance). We can see the SQL that would be executed by calling `->toSql()`:

```php
dd($query->toSql());
// SELECT * FROM players WHERE related_id = ? AND name = ?
```

(Replace `related_id` with whatever `$this` represents in the original question).

Chaining the method `->count()` will execute this as a `SELECT count(...) ...` query, instead of counting the length of the `Collection`.

So, to put it all together; Query directly against the Database using `->players()`, execute a `->count()` or `->exists()` query:

```php
return !$this->players()->where('name', $value)->count();  // 0 or # > 1
// OR
return !$this->players()->where('name', $value)->exists(); // true or false
```